# stored proc: multiple query in case when/ if else

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN CASE assetTypeNo 
WHEN 0 THEN 
( 
SELECT * 
FROM 
books 
) 
WHEN 1 
THEN 
SELECT * 
FROM magazines 
END; 
END
```

In creating stored procedures in mySQL.Is this possible? If so. Please help. I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: see the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName
BEGIN 
IF assetTypeNo = 0 THEN 
   SELECT * 
   FROM ;
ELSEIF assetTypeNo = 1 THEN
   SELECT * 
   FROM magazines 
END; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax was incorrect. Try this script -

```
BEGIN

  CASE assetTypeNo
  WHEN 0 THEN 
    SELECT * FROM books;
  WHEN 1 THEN 
    SELECT * FROM magazines;
  END CASE; 

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This should work.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%' PROCEDURE `test_proc`(
        IN assetTypeNo INTEGER(11)
    )
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    CASE assetTypeNo
      WHEN 0 THEN SELECT * FROM `books`;
      WHEN 1 THEN SELECT * FROM `magazines` ;
      ELSE
        BEGIN
        END;
    END CASE; 

END;
```